# Помогите разобраться в Цикле, while

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

# create a sequence of words to choose from
WORDS = ("python", "jumble", "easy", "difficult", "answer", "xylophone")
# pick one word randomly from the sequence
word = random.choice(WORDS)
# create a variable to use later to see if the guess is correct
correct = word
points = 50

# create a jumbled version of the word
jumble = ""
while word:
    position = random.randrange(len(word))
    jumble += word[position]
    word = word[:position] + word[(position + 1):]

# start the game
print(
    """
               Welcome to Word Jumble!

       Unscramble the letters to make a word.
    (Press the enter key at the prompt to quit.)
    """
)
print("The jumble is:", jumble)
print(word)
guess = input("\nYour guess(if you need advance press 1): ")
if guess == '1':
    points -= 5
    if correct == 'python':
        print("pyt")
    elif correct == 'jumble':
        print("jum")
    elif correct == 'easy':
        print("ea")
    elif correct == 'difficult':
        print("diff")
    elif correct == 'answer':
        print("ans")
    elif correct == 'xylophone':
        print("xylo")
else:
    print("Sorry, that's not it.")

while guess != correct and guess != "":
    guess = input("Your guess(if you need advance press 1): ")
    if guess == '1':
        points -= 5
        if correct == 'python':
            print("pyt")
        elif correct == 'jumble':
            print("jum")
        elif correct == 'easy':
            print("ea")
        elif correct == 'difficult':
            print("diff")
        elif correct == 'answer':
            print("ans")
        elif correct == 'xylophone':
            print("xylo")
        if guess == '1':
            continue
    print("Sorry, that's not it.")

if guess == correct:
    print("That's it!  You guessed it!\n")

print(f"Thanks for playing. Your score:{points}")

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Это игра, которая разбрасывает буквы в слове и просит разгадать что за слово, я не могу разобраться что происходит в этом цикле, очень прошу- простыми словами и детально обьясните что происходит здесь:

```
# create a jumbled version of the word
jumble = ""
while word:
    position = random.randrange(len(word))
    jumble += word[position]
    word = word[:position] + word[(position + 1):]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
    jumble = "" # объявляем пустую переменную типа str
    while word:  # до тех пор пока в слове осталась хотя-бы одна буква
                 # (Не пустая строка == True, пустая == False)

        position = random.randrange(len(word)) # определяем рандомную позицию
        jumble += word[position]    # к переменной jumble добавляем симовл находящийся в позиции position
        word = word[:position] + word[position + 1:] # делаем word равным части word до position + часть слова после position
    # тоесть удаляем из него символ с индексом position
    # и так пока word не станет == ''
```

В догонку к коментарию:

```
lword = list(word)
random.shuffle(lword)
jumble = ''.join(lword)
```

Сделает тоже самое

Comment: И в сторону (после увиденного): *на Питоне тоже можно писать на Си* :) (нет, к вам претензий никаких)

Comment: @0andriy, как же я соскучился по Вашим комментариям, еще с башевских веток ))) (не сарказм) Всегда в точку )))

Comment: word = word[:position] + word[(position + 1):] - можете поподробнее обьяснить эту переменную, как отсюда могут пропасть все буквы если мы все время приравниваем ее к срезам

Comment: `word = 'abcdef'`, `position = 2`, `word[position] = 'c'`, `word[:position] = 'ab'`, `word[(position + 1):] = 'def'`, `'ab' + 'def' == 'abdef'` и так пока `word != ''`

Comment: @Wairua Господи, благодаря вам на меня будто луч просвещения попал, спасибо)